# CKEditor outputting text doesn't match input when using htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($variable))

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor to input rich text into my database, which works except the formatting is not the same when I try to output the rich text the user entered.  The position of elements such as pictures is incorrect.

I currently have the following code:

Input:

```
$pitch = htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor1']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE projects SET pitch='$pitch' WHERE id='$proj_id'");
```

Output:

```
$pitch = htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($pitch));
```

The result is then echoed back which creates the incorrect formatting.[image: Input and result of code]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP.

Contents of the framed editor (which you use) is styled by the `contents.css` file which you can find in the main CKEditor directory. However, this stylesheet is not used on your page, so content created in editor is not styled by the same rules.

The correct approach is - style content on your site and then copy (or somehow reuse, e.g. by setting [`config.bodyClass`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-bodyClass) and [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss)) these styles in editor contents.

Remember, that you also need to set styles available in styles drop down. They are by default configured as for the sample, but when you'll change available styles, you need to update `styles.js` file too.

Comment: Thanks!  I included the contents.css style sheet and it looks much better already.  Isn't there a way that I can display the result in a ckeditor textarea but without the editing options (except for read only mode)?  Wouldn't that be a better approach?

Comment: Hmm... I don't fully get what you want to do. If you want to display content of editor exactly how it looked like while editing, then you should check [inline editing](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline).

Comment: Yeah, my problem is I don't actually understand how to output the xhtml produced by ckeditor so that it looks exactly as it did in the editor.  So I'm thinking of just enabling read-only mode and hide the fromatting toolbar so that the output content looks the same as it did with editing.

Comment: "So I'm thinking of just enabling read-only mode and hide the fromatting toolbar" - this is very ugly hack :P And also - it may not work correctly. Check inline editing or tune `contents.css`.

Comment: I know but honestly I'm at my wit's end...  How would using inline editing help me to output the submitted content?  Sorry, I'm probably missing something really obvious :)

Comment: You won't need any help - you just need to load data saved from editors to the same places where they were edited. So the tricky part is - your page needs to have two modes - normal and edit. So you don't edit articles in your separate backend CMS anymore, but directly on the page. The same which then people see.